# How to auto login to microsoft store?

Tags: c#, store, autologin

[microsoft store screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N0Ld.jpg)

I want an automatic login to the Microsoft store application with my e-mail and password address (without showing the password to the user).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-8.0

[Video demo](https://streamable.com/iuq6ns)